# What projectiles does Slow Time not affect?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

I have noticed that certain things, such as the spikes from Quill mobs and mortar fire are not influenced by Slow Time's 90% projectile slow. What other sorts of ranged attacks fall into this category?

Comment: Very good question. +1!

Comment: That would suggest that items thrown/fired with an arc are not slowed. This requires some SCIENCE!

Answer (score 1):

Azmodan's big ball of death fire thing is not slowed...and rather painful.

Answer (score 0):

Idk about the mortar abilites, but I've had slow time effect the straight fireball ability, the posion bees, wind-up melee attacks, and arrow-type abilities (skeleton archers, etc).

Answer (score -1):

My team had a mob that had this ability and our Witch Doctors bears weren't slowed. I have no idea what the skill is called.

Comment: Those are called Missle Dampening. They won't affect anything that isn't a projectile.

Comment: @Lunco You seem to be talking about the "Missile Dampening" ability that can only spawn on Rare monsters. I believe the OP is asking specifically about projectiles the Wizards skill "Slow Time" affects or does not...